# How to fix problem of software closing after it opens?

Tags: windows, wine

My wine package is 8.0 staging. I installed a program called hakchi using wine. It installed successfully and seemed to open fine. However over and over again it seems to close almost immediately after updating and downloading important data, what do I do? Also I think in wine configure i adjusted it to windows vista, but changed it to windows 7.

Comment: I'd say a wine forum would be a better place to post this.

Comment: Maybe use a emulator which runs native on Linux? https://fceux.com/  https://github.com/higan-emu/higan